# Running Pub Install has encountered an error?

Tags: git, dart, dart-editor

[image: Screen shot of the pubinstall issue]

The given below is the issue i started to face during pub install suddenly.

Kindly help me out since I need to update the dependencies to make sure the app starts working with my sql.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with corobot-web. It doesn't look to be pub's fault :-/